# Net Use not passing credentials - Non domain accounts

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to copy a file from a non domain server, but everytime we run the net use command it will hang and then say that the specified network password is not correct.

```
 - net use \\IpAddress\Folder\ password /user:userid
```

But if we remove the user from the command, then we get prompted for a password. Enter in the same password that we had input previously, and it works.

```
 - net use \\IpAddress\Folder\ /user:userid
```

What is the disconnect here? Or is there a way to open this share to all users and not have a need for credentials?

Comment: Try put double quotes around the password

Comment: and write password after user i.e `/user:username "password"`

Comment: Tried /user:username "password"
Works with windows 10, fails with windows 7.

Comment: Is the share name the same as the folder?  Normally it is: `\\computer\sharename` at a minimum and you can go deeper with folders if you want to.

Comment: @MikeMartinez  Try put `"password"` before `/user`. Also it's better to quote `\\remote\path` too.

Comment: Is there an error message? _try leaving `echo`ing on and either running it directly at the command prompt, or adding a pause command to your batch file, to check for errors._